# Print duplicate JSON Array in console using Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I have a set of JSON array which looks like below, I want to print the duplicate JSON which has the same URL.

```
var temp = [
  {
     "name":"Allen",
     "site":"www.google.com/allen"
  },
  {
     "name":"Chris",
     "site":"www.google.com/chris"
  },
  {
     "name":"Tom Allen",
     "site":"www.google.com/allen"
  }
]
```

expected output :

```
duplicate = {
 "name":"Allen",
 "site":"www.google.com/allen"
}
```

Comment: add code what had you tried.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let temp = [
{
 "name":"Allen",
 "site":"www.google.com/allen"
},
{
 "name":"Chris",
 "site":"www.google.com/chris"
},
{
 "name":"Tom Allen",
 "site":"www.google.com/allen"
}
];

let dups = temp.reduce((r,t,i,o)=>{
   o.some((x,i2)=>x.site===t.site && i!==i2) && !r.some(x=>x.site===t.site) && r.push(t);
   return r;
},[]);

console.log(dups);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the `duplicate` variable should be an array as there could be more than one duplicate objects. And the first item should not be selected as a duplicate item. You can try this-

```js
var temp = [{"name":"Allen","site":"www.google.com/allen"},{"name":"Chris","site":"www.google.com/chris"},{"name":"Tom Allen","site":"www.google.com/allen"}];

const hashMap = {};
const duplicate = [];

temp.forEach(item => {
  if (hashMap[item.site] !== undefined) {
    duplicate.push(item);
  } else {
    hashMap[item.site] = item;
  }
});

console.log(duplicate);
```

Comment: can u pls explain this sir if (hashMap[item.site] !== undefined)

Comment: It's just a normal Object where I put the `site` as key and `item` as the value and check if already the `site` already exists into the object. If exists that means it's duplicated.

Answer (score 0):

In a functional way:

My function will consider as "duplicate" all occurrences that isn't the first.
You will need "the last", just reverse the collection.

```js
// f: a function that receives one element from coll and returns a `key` that identify the element
// coll: any collection that implements .reduce
var duplicatesBy = (f, coll) => {
  var rf = ({dups, seen}, el) => {
    var id = f(el)
    return {
      dups: (seen.includes(id) ? [... dups, el] : dups),
      seen: [... seen, id]
    }
  }
  var { dups } = coll.reduce(rf, {dups: [], seen: []})
  return dups
}

console.log(duplicatesBy(({site})=> site, temp))

//output:
// [ { name: 'Tom Allen', site: 'www.google.com/allen' } ]
```